# Mvvmcross: Interacting with android service

Tags: android, android-service, mvvmcross

I am thinking about using mvvmcross in one of the projects. For now I am just exploring the mvvmcross and going through different articles, but I cannot find anything relating to mvvmcross and android service. How to start, stop or bind to service in view-model. What is the "best" approach when dealing with services? Does anybody has a link or anything on the subject.

Uros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I treat Android services, ios long running tasks and Windows background tasks as separate 'services' and they don't generally interact directly with the ViewModels, but instead interact via messaging, via data stores, etc. Specifically for Android, you may need to use View/Activity level hooks like service local binding (see [Android - Service and Activity interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065850/android-service-and-activity-interaction))

When the background services share the same process (same memory space) as the ViewModels, then one thing that can seem a little awkward is initialising shared IoC and any required application singletons. However, generally this doesn't seem to be too hard to do - e.g. see questions like [Using MvvmCross from content providers and activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862980/using-mvvmcross-from-content-providers-and-activities) and [MvvmCross initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466140/mvvmcross-initialization)

I haven't personally seen enough examples of this type of app to work out if there's a few common architectural patterns that could be supplied at an mvvm-platform level. I'd love to see more examples and more people talking about architectural ideas in this area.

Comment: Hi Stuart. Thank you for your answer. While I was thinking about possible approaches to my problem, messaging was the first thing that crossed my mind since that is the way I would go when using WPF and needed view-model view interaction. So I will check out the provided links and see where it leads me. By the way - you did an excelent job with the whole mvvmcross project and I really like your N+1 tutorial series.

Comment: @Stuart I would agree that specialized long running services such as the Android should remain separate, however, how can we enable dependency injection into these services when we want them to boot up, in a similar way we inject into view models.

Comment: The answer already contains links to questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466140/mvvmcross-initialization - that should help?